# Is there a way to retrieve a Dictionary key using an equivalent key?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using a custom class as a key for a Dictionary(TKey, TValue).  The class overrides GetHashCode and Equals, etc.

What I'd like to be able to do is add a key/value pair; later, generate a new key that is equivalent to the first key (same hash code, Equals returns true), and, using this equivalent key, retrieve not only the value, but also a reference to the *original* key that was first added to the Dictionary.

Example:

```
var keyA = new KeyClass("abc123");
var keyB = new KeyClass("abc123"); // same as far as dictionary is concerned

var dict = new Dictionary<KeyClass, Object>();

dict.Add(keyA, value);
```

Now how can I get a reference to keyA from the Dictionary using keyB?

It seems like this should be easy to do without enumerating the Keys collection, since the Dictionary has these keys hashed already, but I can't find anything built into the Dictionary class.  Am I missing something?  As it stands now I'll either have to use a bidirectional dictionary and do a reverse lookup, or (my preference in this case) "enhance" the class I'm using for values so they store references to the original keys.

Comment: "The class overrides GetHashCode and Equals, etc" - what could possibly go wrong?  ;)

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve? Why enumerating Keys is not enough?

Comment: @MitchWheat It's required to override these methods when implementing `IEquatable` in a class. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131190(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Smeegs: yes I know that!

Comment: @MitchWheat, ah.  I thought you were implying that he shouldn't do that.

Comment: I'm implying that 9 times out of 10, people get it wrong.

Comment: Yup....which bring us to the this point...@Rich, we need to see your class definition.

Comment: I'm aware of the pitfalls, but this is a supported way of using the Dictionary class. For purposes of the question, I'm assuming I haven't screwed it up.

Answer (score 1):

Well, @AD.Net is appropriate answer which is mostly true when overriding `GetHashCode()` and `Equals()`

```
public class KeyClass 
{

   public readonly string key;

   public KeyClass(string key)
   {
      this.key = key;
   }

   public override bool Equals(object other)
   {
       if (other == null)
         return false;

       // Casting object other to type KeyClass
       KeyClass obj = other as KeyClass;
       if (obj == null)
         return false;

        return this.key == other.key;
   }

   public override int GetHashCode()
   {
        return this.key.GetHashCode();
   }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't explicit casting throw an exception if `other` can't be cast to `KeyClass`? Maybe `KeyClass obj = other as KeyClass;` is more appropriate here. (of course, checking for `null` afterwards is a must).

Comment: @Corak Yes, I try to answer as fast as I can, so sorry. If `KeyClass obj = (KeyClass) obj` that would be raise `InvalidCastException` and I know that

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to tell me here - I'm not trying to design KeyClass, I'm trying to get a reference to the instance of KeyClass that was originally added to the dictionary.